# tyepescript error while using useLoaderData hook and datatable shadcn-ui

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-typescript, shadcnui

i was trying to fetch a patient list by sending api request to my express backend and it returns. however since i am using the new react-router-dom(Data Api), the useLoaderData hook returns the data but when i pass it to the Datatable component i get a type error, i was able to pass this error by making the type definition to any in the component but that is a way around and still i am struggling with the type error when i try to get the length of the data in the heading component below?

i tired to type the type right in the usage of the hook but it says, it expects 0 type argument. Also tried to type in the const definition and generic typing , it does not work?

```
Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'PatientColumn[]'.ts(2322)
data-table.tsx(26, 3): The expected type comes from property 'data' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & DataTableProps<PatientColumn, unknown>'
(property) DataTableProps<PatientColumn, unknown>.data: PatientColumn[]
```

```
import { ColumnDef } from "@tanstack/react-table";

// import CellAction from "./cell-action"

import { Plus } from "lucide-react";

import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import Heading from "@/components/ui/heading";
import { Separator } from "@/components/ui/separator";
import { DataTable } from "@/components/ui/data-table";
import { useLoaderData, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

type PatientColumn = {
  id: string;
  // photo: string;
  fullName: string;
  age: string;
  sex: string;
  phone: string;
  email: string;
  doctor: string;
  injury: string;
  dateOfVisit: string;
};

export const patientDataLoader = async () => {
  const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/api/patients");
  return response.data;
}

const DashboardPage: React.FC = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const data = useLoaderData();

  return (
    <div className="flex-col">
      <div className="flex-1 space-y-4 p-8 pt-1">
        <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
          <Heading
            title={`Patients List (${data?.length || 0})`}
            description="Manage patients information "
          />
          <Button onClick={() => navigate(`/dashboard/patient`)}>
            <Plus className="mr-2 w-4 h-4" />
            Add New
          </Button>
        </div>
        <Separator />
        <DataTable columns={columns} data={data} searchKey="fullName"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DashboardPage;

// This type is used to define the shape of our data.
// You can use a Zod schema here if you want.

const columns: ColumnDef<PatientColumn>[] = [
  // {
  //   accessorKey: "photo",
  //   header: "Photo",
  // },
  {
    accessorKey: "fullName",
    header: "Full name",
  },
  {
    accessorKey: "age",
    header: "Age",
  },
  {
    accessorKey: "sex",
    header: "Sex",
  },
  {
    accessorKey: "phone",
    header: "Phone",
  },
  {
    accessorKey: "email",
    header: "Email",
  },
  {
    accessorKey: "doctor",
    header: "Doctor",
  },
  {
    accessorKey: "injury",
    header: "Injury",
  },
  {
    accessorKey: "dateOfVisit",
    header: "Date",
  },
  // {
  //   id: "actions",
  //   cell: ({row}) => <CellAction data={row.original} />
  // },
];
```